# Modifying aro_aco entries?

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHPs ACL to handle user permissions.

When a user creates a, lets say *Post*, I automatically create an ACO for that post, and *allow* the user to access it.

But, if I would like to change the user later on so that a different user "takes over" the ownership of the post, what would I do in the ACL?

Is there a delete/remove ACL function I can use to remove rows, and the add the new relationship?

I thought about using *deny* on the old user, and then *allow all* on the new one, but it would be  messy if the parent group has both allow/deny in the structure.

Are there any alternatives, other than using manual sql queries?

Comment: I'd recommend ACL for group-based permissions and leave the individual permissions to your code in the controller or model.  In your posts table, you can have user_id or owner_id (or both) - and only allow that user to modify/delete it.

Comment: Thank you Dave. What I want is to deny all other users to see the post. Would you recommend me to just look if the user and the post are connected(with foreign key), instead of using ACL?

Comment: Yes - everyone that I've spoken with agrees that row-specific ACL is overkill.  Plus, what if your user is set to active=0 or something - their ID still shows them as owner per ACL.